# Http Error 503 - When trying to open https local web server

Tags: http, https, windows-server-2016, http-status-code-503, iis-manager

Any help would be appreciated! I am working on this local web server and we started getting the following error out of nowhere: HTTP Error 503. The Service is unavailable. However when accessing the same site with http it works just fine. This happened on 2 of the servers but the other one fixed itself over the weekend. I cant find any differences within the ISS Manager, network settings, or time/date. I did notice a windows update & a windows security update. Any hints or tricks I can try besdes restarting/stopping/starting the service over?

I tried restarting the server -> matching dns routing to the same as the other servers -> checking event logs -> server logs -> ISS manager logs -> I think I checked everything however I am new to this ISS manager stuff. The certificates look good too so I am lost at this point.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.